# Utility api to convert bson document to csv

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-java, spring-mongo

Is there any utility jar library available to convert bson document to csv with keys as headers of the csv file ?

Comment: Would need more details. Where is the BSON from? Is it exported from MongoDB, or dynamically queried from MongoDB? Does it have to be a jar, or a command line tool is sufficient? Please also post an example of the input & the desired output.

Comment: It is a dynamic query done from java api ,  i need the queried document to be converted to CSV